# Does this work: EF Core 3.1, multiple (0..1)-to-1 relationships

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, relationship

This started out as a question about how to do this, I spent most of the day spinning around, then in the process of trying to ask a good question, I think I solved my problem. Since I had the question written and the example code (at least five iterations), I am going to post it anyway, and ask this:

- Does this sound like a valid approach?
- Am I missing something I'll regret?
- Is there any simple way to drop the IX on CountryID? It won't be discriminatory (90% of addresses will be in CA, another 9% in US, and maybe a couple of far-flung ones).

It may also help anyone else searching as the previous answers I found either were for other/older versions of EF or different scenarios (like using a billing and a shipping address).

--

Here's the question and what i think I found as a solution:

I want to model zero-or-1 to 1 relationships between mailing addresses and the other entities that use them.

Given:

- prefer to keep all of the postal addresses in the same table.
- a user can have one mailing address or none.
- a branch office can have one mailing address or none (none would be uncommon, but possible)
- the addresses are not shared (that is, if two users happen to have the same address, it would end up being duplicated with two different keys; and a user and a branch do not have the same address)

I ended up with these classes:

```
public class PostalAddress
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    // a bunch of typical address stuff omitted.
    public string postalCode { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Country")]
    public string countryID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(6)]
    [ForeignKey("Branch")]
    public string branchID { get; set; }      // This address is used by a branch

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int? userID { get; set; }      // This address is used by a user

    public Country? country { get; set; }     // Address has a many-to-1 to country
    public Branch? branch { get; set; }
    public User? user { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
}

public class Branch
{
    [DisplayName("ID")]
    [MaxLength(6)]
    public string branchID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    [Key]
    [MaxLength(4)]
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Country Code")]
    // countryID is the ISO Alpha 2 Code, but this name is simpler and meets EF Conventions
    public string countryID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Country")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Sort Order")]
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(4)]
    [DisplayName("ISO Alpha-3 Code")]
    public string A3 { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(60)]
    [DisplayName("English Common Name")]
    public string name_en { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(60)]
    [DisplayName("French Common Name")]
    public string name_fr { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("ISO Numeric Code")]
    public int numeric { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(70)]
    [DisplayName("English Formal Name")]
    public string formal_name_en { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(70)]
    [DisplayName("English Short Name")]
    public string short_name_en { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(70)]
    [DisplayName("French Formal Name")]
    public string formal_name_fr { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(30)]
    [DisplayName("Capital")]
    public string Capital { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(4)]
    [DisplayName("Internet TLD")]
    public string TLD { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PostalAddress> postalAddress;
```

}

The annotations and conventions seemed to create the FK relationships, but nothing was guaranteeing that it couldn't be one-to-many. So, adding this Fluent API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PostalAddress>()
            .HasOne(b => b.branch)
            .WithOne();

        modelBuilder.Entity<PostalAddress>()
            .HasOne(u => u.user)
            .WithOne();
    }
```

Seems to have created everything I need. The SQL has FK's from the addresses to each of the other tables and a unique index to enforce the "one-ness".

```
CREATE TABLE [PostalAddress] (
    [ID] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [postalCode] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [countryID] nvarchar(4) NULL,
    [branchID] nvarchar(6) NULL,
    [userID] int NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_PostalAddress] PRIMARY KEY ([ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_PostalAddress_Branch_branchID] FOREIGN KEY ([branchID]) REFERENCES [Branch] ([branchID]) ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_PostalAddress_Country_countryID] FOREIGN KEY ([countryID]) REFERENCES [Country] ([countryID]) ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_PostalAddress_User_userID] FOREIGN KEY ([userID]) REFERENCES [User] ([ID]) ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
GO

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_PostalAddress_branchID] ON [PostalAddress] ([branchID]) WHERE [branchID] IS NOT NULL;
GO

CREATE INDEX [IX_PostalAddress_countryID] ON [PostalAddress] ([countryID]);
GO

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_PostalAddress_userID] ON [PostalAddress] ([userID]) WHERE [userID] IS NOT NULL;
GO
```

Did I miss anything? Any suggestions?

Comment: It's basically one-to-many relationship. Please have a look at the microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all pretty standard, EF Core recognizes one to one relationships without needing to do configuration (as long as you're defining the foreign keys) so you don't have to configure one to one relationships (in most cases).

You can either expose the entity id as a foreign key in the other entity or define a custom one your self and decorate it with the foreign key attribute pointing to the navigation property.

As long as you're defining nullable foreign keys you can achieve the "zero-or-1 to 1 relationships" i.e, a principal entity can contain dependent entity or null.

I would add the navigation properties on both ends of the relationship so i can access information more easily for different scenarios.

And its recommended to name your entity ids like this: PostalAddressId, BranchId...

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public virtual PostalAddress PostalAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Branch
{
    [DisplayName("ID")]
    [MaxLength(6)]
    public string BranchID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public virtual PostalAddress PostalAddress { get; set; }
}
```

And since you're defining a one to one then the addresses won't be shared by design.

**Edit:**

The fluent api is essential but ef core can understand the (standard) one to one relationship by convention based on the defined foreign keys i.e, when you define the first entity id in the other entity ef core can pick up on it without needing the fluent api (so its not needed in this case only) but as long as you're naming the foreign keys differently your relationship will need the fluent api or the data annotations to point to the defined foreign key because now you're not following the convention and you need to teach efcore which is the foreign key that you want.

See [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-one-relationship-configuration). This site has alot of topics covered about efcore